# Ammo js rotate Kinematic object

Tags: javascript, rotation, ammo.js

I have a kinematic sphere moving in x and z axis, but my sphere is moving without rotation how can I rotate my sphere while she is moving ?
`updateBallMove` method :

```
    let scalingFactor = startVelocity;

    let translateFactor = tmpPos.set(ballObject.move.x, ballObject.move.y, ballObject.move.z);

    translateFactor.multiplyScalar(scalingFactor);

    ballObject.translateX(translateFactor.x);
    ballObject.translateY(translateFactor.y);
    ballObject.translateZ(translateFactor.z);

    ballObject.getWorldPosition(tmpPos);
    ballObject.getWorldQuaternion(tmpQuat);

    let physicsBody = ballObject.userData.physicsBody;

    let ms = physicsBody.getMotionState();
    if ( ms ) {

        ammoTmpPos.setValue(tmpPos.x, tmpPos.y, tmpPos.z);
        ammoTmpQuat.setValue( tmpQuat.x, tmpQuat.y, tmpQuat.z, tmpQuat.w);


        tmpTrans.setIdentity();
        tmpTrans.setOrigin( ammoTmpPos ); 
        tmpTrans.setRotation( ammoTmpQuat ); 

        ms.setWorldTransform(tmpTrans);

    }
   let angVel = ballObject.getAngularVelocity();
   ballObject.userData.setAngularVelocity( new Ammo.btVector3( angVel.x, angVel.y, angVel.z ));

  }
```

EDIT : I tried with angularVelocity but I get a `TypeError: ballObject.getAngularVelocity is not a function`

Comment: `console.log` is your best friend while debugging JS.  Try `console.log(ballObject)` right before the `let angVel` statement and see what ballObject has in it in the console window.

Comment: I found it was  `let angVel = physicsBody.getAngularVelocity();
  physicsBody.setAngularVelocity( new Ammo.btVector3( angVel.x, angVel.y, angVel.z ));` but it's doesn't affect the ball rotation ...